# Function success in Ajax Jquery isn't executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code in Jquery and it displays always error function:

```
function getStatistic6() {

var response;
var allstat6 = [];
var dstart = "01.01.2014";
var dend = "03.31.2014";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:52251/Service1.asmx/Statistic_6_Entete',
    data: { "start": dstart, "end": dend },
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        response = msg.d;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.Items.length; i++) {
            var j = 0;
            allstat6[i] = [response.Items[i].Date, response.Items[i].Piece, response.Items[i].Tiers, response.Items[i].AmoutHT, response.Items[i].AmountTTC, response.Items[i].Quantite];
        }
        fillDataTable6(allstat6);
        $('table').visualize({ type: 'line' });

    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("error loading statistic 6");
    }
});
}
```

When I check the debug, my web service method returns the good xml response.
When I display the status and error with alert, I have :

[image]

What's wrong?

**EDIT :**

I have this in my webservice.asmx :

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public ResponseStatistic_6_Entete Statistic_6_Entete(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        ...
    }
```

[image]

**Sorry I misspoke, I want to return json objects. I use other methods whose datatype is json and it works very well. When I say that it returns the correct xml response, it is because I saw it in the debug that's all. I do not understand why with this method one, it does not work!**

Comment: The JSON you're loading isn't valid.

Comment: Does your service in fact return json? Doesnt it return soap by any chance?

Comment: I edited my post, you can see.

Comment: @Jayce: I don't see any JSON in the (updated) question. Look at what your server is *actually* sending back to the client, and validate *that*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : I use others web service methods with the same syntax and it works well. When I say, it returns the good xml response, this is beacause I saw this in the debug. There are "parameter", "en-tetes", "response" and "xml". And I said xml response like that. You can see the picture

Comment: @Jayce: Quentin's answered your question, if you hadn't noticed. If you're not sending back JSON, don't tell jQuery you're sending back JSON.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I misspoke, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with JSON.stringify:

```
function getStatistic6() {

var response;
var allstat6 = [];
var dstart = "01.01.2014";
var dend = "03.31.2014";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:52251/Service1.asmx/Statistic_6_Entete',
    data: {"start": JSON.stringify(dstart), "end": JSON.stringify(dend) },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        response = msg.d;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.Items.length; i++) {
            var j = 0;
            allstat6[i] = [response.Items[i].Date, response.Items[i].Piece, response.Items[i].Tiers, response.Items[i].AmoutHT, response.Items[i].AmountTTC, response.Items[i].Quantite];
        }
        fillDataTable6(allstat6);
        $('table').visualize({ type: 'line' });

    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error loading statistic 6");
        alert("Status: " + textStatus+"\n"+"Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> my web service method returns the good xml response.

but

> dataType: 'json',

You've told your code to ignore what the server says the data is and to try to parse it as JSON. Since it is not JSON but is XML, it fails.

Remove the `dataType` property.

---

Then you have:

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < response.Items.length; i++) {
> ```

but you will need to replace that with DOM methods (or jQuery wrappers around them) to access the data since it will be an XML DOM and not a simple JS object.

Comment: I use others methods with returns json object, I would do the same thing with this method.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in question, the web service response in `xml` then please use 
`dataType:"xml"` in `ajax` function

As well as use `$.parseXML()` for parse XML response data.

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify `dataType:"xml"`, if the server is returning the correct content-type headers then jQuery can just run off those. And don't use `$.parseXML()`, the data will have already been parsed into a DOM.

Comment: @Quentin, you are right, `$.parseXML()` will useful when server response haven't valid header.

Comment: @Girish: Well, you wouldn't do `dataType: "xml"` "as well as" `$.parseXML`. You'd do one or the other (or better yet, fix the server).

Comment: If I put  "ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json" on my web service method, is that not correct?